Sensitive Transimpedance Amplifier frequency bandwidth
I've built the transimpedance amplifier based on this project Sensitive Transimpedance Amplifier Oscillates. I've used op amp LMC6001, symmetrically power 5 volts, feedback resistor Rf = 100MΩ, feedback capacitor Cf = 100 pF. The cutoff frequency is fc = 15.92 Hz.
I have some input impulses which have the frequency about 1.5 kHz and I wanted to be able to precisely register their maxima. Does it mean that, I have to change cutoff frequency to higher?
The question is what should I modify in this circuit to let me detect 1.5 kHz pulses?
Thank you for your help.

Not clear what you're trying to do. It's quite common to use a transimpedance amplifier with a long time constant to measure short pulses. It converts pulses into steps, and your downstream machinery measures the steps. See, for example, https://www.amptek.com/-/media/ametekamptek/documents/resources/dpp_theory.pdf?la=en&revision=0b5bb590-e4b6-4038-ab67-3516060fa5e7

I thought it acts like a low pass filter which attenuates my 1.5 kHz pulses because it has cutoff frequency fc = 15.92 Hz much lower than the frequency of my signal.

@PawełChmolewski That's not a particularly useful way to think about it for pulses. Yes, in the Fourier domain it attenuates high frequencies. But in the time domain it turns impulses to steps. The height of a step is easier to measure than the height of a pulse.
